# How can I trigger a method in a subcomponent when parent changes props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React web application that has three components, a parent and two child subcomponents. I've left out the JavaScript related to `<HeaderComponent />` because it isn't relevant to this question.

```js
class App extends Component {

    token = null;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            AllInvoices: [],
            CurrentInvoice: null
        };
         this.setCurrentInvoice = this.setCurrentInvoice.bind(this);
     }

     setCurrentInvoice = (sharedValue) => {
        this.setState({
            CurrentInvoice: sharedValue
        });
      }

     componentDidMount()
     {
         fetch("http://api.app.local/api/getALLinvoices", {
             "method": "GET"
          })
          .then(resp => {
              this.setState({
                  AllInvoices: resp.Result
                  CurrentInvoice: resp.Result[0]
              });
          });
     }

     componentDidUpdate()
     {
         // this DOES trigger
         console.log("App componentDidUpdate triggered");
     }


     render() {

        return (
            <>
              <HeaderComponent AllInvoices={this.state.AllInvoices} setCurrentInvoice={this.setCurrentInvoice} />
              <MainFormComponent CurrentInvoice={this.state.CurrentInvoice} /> 
            </>
        )
    }
}


class MainFormComponent extends Component {

    token = null;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Field1Value: "",
            Field2Value: "",
            Field3Value: "",
            // ...
            Field12Value: ""
        };
     }

     componentDidUpdate()
     {
         //> For some reason this does NOT trigger when CurrentInvoice is updated
         console.log("MainFormComponent componentDidUpdate triggered");
     }

     getInvoiceDetailsAndUpdateForm = () => 
     {
        fetch("http://api.app.local/api/getinvoicedetails", {
           "method": "POST",
           "body": {
              "invoice_id": this.props.CurrentInvoice.Id
            }
        })
        .then(resp => {
           /*
            * Run various business logic and update 12+ form fields with AJAX response
            *
            */
         });
     }


     render() {

        return (
            <>
              <TextField Value={this.state.Field1Value} />
              <TextField Value={this.state.Field2Value} />
              <TextField Value={this.state.Field2Value} />
              { /* ... */ }
              <TextField Value={this.state.Field12Value} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

class HeaderComponent extends Component {

    token = null;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            MiscVariable: ""        
        };
     }

     setUpdateCurrentInvoice = (row) => 
     {
        this.props.setCurrentInvoice(row);
     }


     render() {

        return (
            <>
              {this.props.AllInvoices.map((row, i) => (
              <Button onClick={() => { this.setUpdateCurrentInvoice(row); }} />
              ))}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Within the `App` component an AJAX call returns all invoices, and sets an initial value for `this.state.CurrentInvoice`. Afterwards, buttons in `<HeaderComponent />` or `<MainFormComponent />` can change `CurrentInvoice`.

When `CurrentInvoice` within `App` is changed, I want to trigger `getInvoiceDetailsAndUpdateForm` within the `<MainFormComponent />` so that I can perform another AJAX call and run other business logic within that component.

What I'm finding is that within `<MainFormComponent />` I can't seem to be able to "subscribe" to `props.CurrentInvoice` value changes. Within the `render()` method in that Component I see the change. But, that hasn't helped me because I want to trigger `getInvoiceDetailsAndUpdateForm`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve the outcome I want?

## Update:

The original code I published did not contain code related to the `HeaderComponent`. I've now included that to help draw the whole picture.

Basically what's happening is that the user clicks on a button in `HeaderComponent` which then calls `setCurrentInvoice`. When this happens `componentDidUpdate` is triggered, but only in the parent component. I am trying to figure out why `componentDidUpdate` within `MainFormComponent` is NOT also firing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). You can compare prevProps and currentProps and perform necessary actions

you would want to implement this lifecycle method in your `MainFormComponent`

Also, here's [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/child-componentdidupdate-733t7e?file=/src/App.js) which is emulating the behavior you are having.

if you see `App` is the component storing the state and the handler,
and `ChildComponent` has the `componentDidUpdate` in it
now when you click either in `App` or `AnotherChildComponent`
it fires the state update, since `ChildComponent` has `ComponentDidUpdate` and it is receiving the `counter` prop you can clearly see it printing the previous and current values.

One thing to note - `componentDidUpdate` does not get immediately fired but when the state/prop changes so you may not see it fired on the first render but as soon as your api returns something and updates the state you will see it's getting fired for the 1st time in your `MainForm` component

Also, if you can post some proof of it not firing like screenshot of console.log would be helpful.

I don't see a point of `componentDidUpdate` not firing.

Comment: I tried adding `componentDidUpdate(prevValues)
    {
        console.log("componentDidUpdate triggered", prevValues);
    }` to `MainFormComponent` but it doesn't trigger when `CurrentInvoice` is changed.

Comment: I've updated the code example above to include `componentDidUpdate` so that you can see what I tried. The only time that function triggers, is when the app first launches and the initial value for `CurrentInvoice` is set. Updates to `CurrentInvoice` does NOT trigger `componentDidUpdate` for some reason I can't figure out.

Comment: it does fire !! 
it's probably because you are logging only prevProps so it seems it's not doing anything please log current props as well and you will see... here's the working example https://codesandbox.io/s/child-componentdidupdate-733t7e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I wish this wasn't my response, but I'm NOT getting the same experience in my App.   The `componentDidUpdate()` function is NOT *triggering* in `MainFormComponent`. What can I do to troubleshoot why it isn't triggering?

Comment: as I said did you add this.props to your console.log and see ? I am sure it's the 1st time update and you are just logging the prevProps and you are thinking it's not firing. Beware componentDidUpdate does not get fire the first time like componentDidMount it only fires when component updates. so I am still saying can you share screenshot of console logged prevProps and this.props I really want to see that

Comment: Hi @Anuj, yes. But because `componentDidUpdate` within `MainFormComponent` is not triggering, the `console.log` is not firing. The only component where `componentDidUpdate` IS working is in the `App` parent component. `componentDidUpdate` is not firing in the subcomponents.

Comment: previously I left out the code related to `HeaderComponet`. I've now included that, along with an updated description so to help draw a wider picture of the App.

Comment: that seems strange to me !!! can you check your header component that it's getting the correct row and it is actually firing state update ?